# LINQ to Entities after group by, COUNT and WHERE not working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, group-by, count

I have the following LINQ-to-Entities query for MySQL DB

```
 var data = (from agent in db.User
                            join agentrole in db.UserRole.DefaultIfEmpty() on agent.Id equals agentrole.UserId
                            join role in db.Role.DefaultIfEmpty() on agentrole.RoleId equals role.Id
                            join department in db.Department.DefaultIfEmpty() on role.DepartmentId equals department.Id
                            join client in db.Client.DefaultIfEmpty() on agent.Id equals client.AssignedUserId
                            join aggclient in db.AggClient.DefaultIfEmpty() on client.Id equals aggclient.ClientId
                            group new { agent, department, aggclient} by agent.Id into grp
                            select new
                            {
                                grp.Key,
                                agentName = grp.Max(a => a.agent.FirstName + " " + a.agent.LastName),
                                departmentNames = "",
                                newDepositorsCount = 0,
                                FTDSum = grp.Sum(a => a.aggclient.FirstDepositAmountEuro),
                                depcount =grp.Count(a => a.department != null),
                                aggclientfilter = grp.Where(a => a.aggclient != null && a.aggclient.FirstDepositAmount>0).Sum(a => a.aggclient.FirstDepositAmount)
                            });
```

On the current query, the last two operations are not working.
The entity cannot parse **count** and **where** operations.

Comment: You should use navigation properties, not joins. Then you don't need GroupBy and everything will become much easier to code. If you need help please show the class model and mention your EF version.

Answer (score 0):

change `select clause` to :

```
select new
{
    grp.Key,
    agentName = grp.agent.Max(a => a.FirstName + " " + a.LastName),
    departmentNames = "",
    newDepositorsCount = 0,
    FTDSum = grp.aggclient.Sum(a => a.FirstDepositAmountEuro),
    depcount = grp.department.Count(),
    aggclientfilter = grp.aggclient.Where(a => a.FirstDepositAmount>0).Sum(a => a.FirstDepositAmount)
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you do not use EF Core 5.x, because it supports filtered count.

Problem that there is no correct translation to SQL of such LINQ query. But there are tricks which can return needed result. Also corrected bad LEFT join.

```cs
var data = 
    from agent in db.User
    join agentrole in db.UserRole on agent.Id equals agentrole.UserId into ga
    from agentrole in ga.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join role in db.Role on agentrole.RoleId equals role.Id into gr
    from role in gr.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join department in db.Department on role.DepartmentId equals department.Id into dg
    from department in dg.DefaultIfEmpty()
    join client in db.Client on agent.Id equals client.AssignedUserId
    join aggclient in db.AggClient on client.Id equals aggclient.ClientId into acg
    from aggclient in acg.DefaultIfEmpty()
    group new { agent, department, aggclient} by agent.Id into grp
    select new
    {
        grp.Key,
        agentName = grp.Max(a => a.agent.FirstName + " " + a.agent.LastName),
        departmentNames = "",
        newDepositorsCount = 0,
        FTDSum = grp.Sum(a => a.aggclient.FirstDepositAmountEuro),
        depcount = grp.Sum(a => a.department != null ? 1 : 0),
        aggclientfilter = grp.Sum(a => a.aggclient.FirstDepositAmount > 0 ? a.aggclient.FirstDepositAmount : 0)
    };
```